# Convert Regular expression to a simple one

Tags: c#

I have this expression `(a and b) or not (c and d)`

I want to convert it to a simple one `a and b or not c and or not d`

Is that possible in Regex

thanks

Comment: Give us the actual regex you tried, your input and what worked and what not worked

Comment: The requirement is wierd and i'm not sure i really understand, but i don't think regex is the right tool for it.

Comment: Is this a boolean expression or just some text? Also, what exactly are you converting here? Are you eliminating braces in the expression or applying DeMorgans? Or something else entirely. Also, the result of the conversion doesn't make sense ... what does "not c and or not b" mean? At first glance, it seems like this problem isn't really appropriate for regular expressions at all; perhaps some more details would help the community give you better responses.

Comment: I have some texts contains words and i want to search betwwen them according to this pattern , the word represent by [a-b-c-d] and i want to convert the pattern [(a and b) or not (c and d)

] to [a and b or not c and or not d
] to allow me to make this search ...... thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mixing the concepts of mathematical expressions and regular expressions. These two things have no relation to each other. Regular expressions are a tool for searching and replacing pieces of strings.

It looks like you're trying to apply [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to a boolean expression, changing "not (C and D)" to "not C or not D". That is not text manipulation per se, it is [Boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) and is better solved by lexing/parsing techniques.

This is too large a topic to summarize in one Stack Overflow answer, but as an overview I'd recommend creating an [abstract syntax tree (AST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). An AST for your first expression would look like this:

```
     or
   /    \
 and    not
 / \     |
a   b   and
        / \
       c   d
```

Then you can manipulate the nodes of that tree by applying the rules of Boolean algebra. For instance, De Morgan's law "not (C and D) = not C or not D" is the same as the following sub-tree transformation:

```
 not               or
  |               /  \
 and     -->    not  not 
 / \             |    |
c   d            c    d
```

Comment: I would agree this is certainly not solvable in the general case using regular expressions,  but it is probably solvable in a finite number of specific cases.  Whether regular expressions are viable or sensible would depend how general the solution needs to be.